# How do you categorize groups of people as subjects?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, taxonomy

When compiling published content, one method of sorting or filtering is by *audience*. There, the term “audience” generally implies a curation of material for assumed identities of a readership (articles *for* students or *for* employees or *for* the community to read). It may appear like this:

> **Audience** *<-- the term for people within readership categories*
>
> - Students
> - Employees
> - Community

I’m looking instead for a similar word to “audience” that clearly indicates that the content is grouped by subject *about* those groups of people (articles *about* students or *about* employees or *about* the community), rather than *for* those groups of people:

> **(Requested Word)** *<-- a term for groups of people as subject categories*
>
> - Students
> - Employees
> - Community

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: *Subjects*? *Populations*?

Comment: If they're *my* subjects then they're all "peasants".

Comment: @HotLicks  I think *peasant* is one of the best and most underappreciated epithets in the English language. The Russians still use it daily, kind of where we'd use *hick*, but with much more color and just withering force.

Comment: *Subject group*

Comment: @DanBron - Thanks, I went with "populations". That covered contextual application of the project nicely.

Comment: @DanBron if it makes you happier, 'peasant' is a pretty well used epithet in British-English.

Comment: @Spagirl Ha, that's awesome. I also learned that it's a term of abuse in the gamer subculture, used to put down "casual" gamers who own console (eg PS4, Xbox) gaming systems, as opposed to the ... and here's the cringey part "PC Master Race".

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought that you were looking for [*'demographic'*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demographic) (which means basically the same as 'audience' in this context), but this doesn't cover the the *'articles about students or about employees or about the community'* part of your question.

Since you want a word to describe what the content is about, the best word would be [***'topic'***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/topic), as it describes what a publication is about in the same way *'audience'* describes who the publication is for (was aimed at). Since it is about the 'about', *'topic'* can be on "people" without a problem.

From the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/topic): *'the subject or theme of a [discourse](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discourse?s=t) or of one of its parts'*.

> Topic:
>
> - Students
> - Employees
> - Community/ties

You can then define subtopics if you wish, such as *'What's it like being a student'*, *'Student Housing'*, *'Student Loans'*, etc.

Comment: 'Architecture' = buildings as topics; maybe 'populations'? 'Anthropologies'? Something like that. I'm being lazy, making suggestions rather than answering. 'Topics' seems too broad for the request, 'peoples' too narrow.

Comment: Hmm, what would be to broad about topic when it comes to describing what a book (or discussion, or a lesson) is about? *'Subject'* is a good word too, as would be *'Theme'*. Anyways, for **topic**, the dictionary says: *the subject or theme of a discourse or of one of its parts.* (edited my answer to include this definition)

Comment: @Terah - thanks, but there were other 'topics'; my requested word was only one amongst other topics.

Comment: @JEL: Yes, went with 'populations', but DanBron answered with that as a comment first! (above)
Thanks, all!